# Pythonic way to determine if two given numbers are adjacent in integer sequence

Tags: python, algorithm

Given integers a, b such that a < b; and some ordered iterable sequence of integers, `seq`.  Determine whether `a` and `b` appear adjacent, in that order, anywhere in `seq`

The obvious first pass is :

assume
a < b (if a > b, just switch values).

```
>>> idx = 0
>>> for i in range(0, len(l)):
...     if a == l[i]:
...             idx = i
... 
>>> b == l[idx+1]
```

This feels clumsy.

For example, given

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 8]
```

If a is 1 and b is 3, they are not adjacent, if a is 3 in b is 8, they are.

Something tells me there is a more pythonic way of doing this or that this is a well explored problem, and I am missing a clearer/cleaner way to approach it.

Comment: Unrelated tip: ``for i, v in enumerate(l):``

Comment: This will return all such pairs in a list of tupes
`[(l[i], l[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(l)-1) if l[i] > l[i+1]]`

Comment: I would concentrate on making the specification match the behavior of the code (or vice versa). At the moment they don't do the same thing so one or the other is wrong. You want "Pythonic" but you're floundering at correctness.

Comment: Why not `l.index(a) == l.index(b)-1`?

Comment: @Feodoran That assumes there are no duplicates in the sequence.

Comment: yes, I just saw it as well.

Comment: When you say "ordered", do you mean the input is sorted, or do you just mean the data structure is something like `list` that keeps track of element order?

Comment: I *should* have added that l is sorted without repeats!  Very important detail.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **any** reducer to determine whether any adjacent pair matches (a,b):

```
>>> seq = [1, 2, 3, 8]
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 8
>>> any((seq[i], seq[i+1]) == (a,b) for i in range(len(seq)-1))
True
>>> b = 1
>>> any((seq[i], seq[i+1]) == (a,b) for i in range(len(seq)-1))
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Very short answer using **zip**:

```
(a, b) in zip(seq[:-1], seq[1:])
```

This works when you are allowed to flip

```
(a, b) in zip(seq[:-1], seq[1:]) or (b, a) in zip(seq[:-1], seq[1:])
```

To make it logically correct you can test for `a in seq` first. If it passes then the previous test(s) should hold.

Some info on what the `zip` is doing

```
>>> print seq 
[1, 2, 3, 8]
>>> zip(seq[:-1], seq[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 8)]
```

Using **izip** and **islice** from the itertools package

```
from itertools import izip, islice
N = len(seq)
(a, b) in izip(islice(seq, 0, N - 1), islice(seq, 1, N))
```

Comment: Very shorter `(a, b) in zip(l, l[1:])` but still incorrect,

Comment: @zipa what do you mean?

Comment: This implements something different from what the question text says we need to compute.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate through pairs of the elements in the sequence and check if a pair consists of `a` and `b`. Using the `pairwise` recipe from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
...     x, y = tee(iterable)
...     next(y, None)
...     return zip(x, y)
... 
>>> a, b, seq = 3, 8, [1, 2, 3, 8]
>>> (a, b) in pairwise(seq)
True
```

This will work fast for arbitrary large sequences (unlike list slicing solutions).

Comment: You do not have to create this yourself as the itertools module already has `islice` and `izip`, see the update of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using [binary search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) will be fastest.

The following implementation should be rather fast, will work even if `b > a`, on unsorted lists and if `a` and/or `b` are not present in the list (will return `False` in this case):

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def is_adjacent(a, b, l):
    ind = bisect_left(l,a)
    if ind >= len(l):
        return False
    if l[ind] == a and l[ind+1] == b:
        return True
    else:
        return is_adjacent(a,b,l[ind+1:])

# e.g.
is_adjacent(1, 3, [1, 2, 3, 8])  # gives False
is_adjacent(3, 8, [1, 2, 3, 8])  # gives True
```

Comment: Since, the order of the list is not guaranteed. We cannot apply a binary search approach. O(n) linear search is unavoidable I guess.

Comment: @ArunKumar if we have a first hit exit condition, it needn't be O(n). In fact this solution will exit at first hit and not run through the entire list if the condition is met earlier in the list. Also, the OP writes *ordered iterable sequence of integers*, so this sound pretty ordered to me.

Comment: you are right. I missed the order part in question. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else is implementing something entirely different from what the problem definition says to implement. Specifically, we're supposed to do the following:

> Determine if `a == l[i]` implies `b == l[i+1]` where `i < len(l)`

That doesn't require `a` or `b` to even be in the list, and (if "ordered" isn't intended to mean "sorted") `a` and `b` could show up multiple times in the list.

To determine what the problem definition actually says to determine, we can go through all pairs of adjacent elements and test whether the implication holds:

```
if l and l[-1] == a:
    # Problem definition doesn't say what to do.
    shrug()
return all(x != a or y == b for (x, y) in zip(l[:-1], l[1:]))
```

If we *are* supposed to assume the input is sorted, we can do better with a binary search:

```
import bisect

if l and l[-1] == a:
    # We still don't know what to do for this case.
    shrug()

possible_leftmost_a_index = bisect.bisect_left(l, a)
if possible_leftmost_a_index == len(a):
    # All elements of l are lower than a.
    return True
elif l[possible_leftmost_a_index] != a:
    # a isn't in the list.
    return True
elif l[possible_leftmost_a_index+1] == b:
    # The implication holds. (We don't have to look for more occurrences of a,
    # because bisect guarantees no a occurrences to the left, and everything to
    # the right is greater than a.)
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be broken down into two subproblems:

1. Converting a sequence into a sequence of pairs, e.g. `[a, b, c]` should be converted to `[(a, b), (b, c)]`.
2. Determining whether a given pair `(x, y)` is in the sequence generated in step 1.

You can convert an iterable to a sequence of pairs with:

```
def pairs(collection):
    collection = iter(collection)
    a = next(collection)
    for b in collection:
        yield a, b
        a = b
```

`collection` can be a list or even an infinite generator.

To determine whether `(x, y)` is in the output of `pairs` you just need to do:

```
(x, y) in pairs(seq)
```